# Reading file multiple ways in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to set up a system for running various statistics on a text file. In this endeavor I need to open a file in Python (v2.7.10) and read it both as lines, and as a string, for the statistical functions to work.

So far I have this:

```
import csv, json, re
from textstat.textstat import textstat

file = "Data/Test.txt"
data = open(file, "r")
string = data.read().replace('\n', '')

lines = 0
blanklines = 0
word_list = []
cf_dict = {}
word_dict = {}
punctuations = [",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":"]
sentences = 0
```

This sets up the file and the preliminary variables. At this point, `print textstat.syllable_count(string)` returns a number. Further, I have:

```
for line in data:
    lines += 1    
    if line.startswith('\n'):
        blanklines += 1
    word_list.extend(line.split())
    for char in line.lower():
        cf_dict[char] = cf_dict.get(char, 0) + 1

for word in word_list:
    lastchar = word[-1]
    if lastchar in punctuations:
        word = word.rstrip(lastchar)
    word = word.lower()
    word_dict[word] = word_dict.get(word, 0) + 1

for key in cf_dict.keys():
    if key in '.!?':
        sentences += cf_dict[key]

number_words = len(word_list)
num = float(number_words)
avg_wordsize = len(''.join([k*v for k, v in word_dict.items()]))/num
mcw = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in word_dict.items()], reverse=True)

print( "Total lines: %d" % lines )
print( "Blank lines: %d" % blanklines )
print( "Sentences: %d" % sentences )
print( "Words: %d" % number_words )

print('-' * 30)
print( "Average word length: %0.2f" % avg_wordsize )
print( "30 most common words: %s" % mcw[:30] )
```

But this fails as `22 avg_wordsize = len(''.join([k*v for k, v in word_dict.items()]))/num` returns a *ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero*. However, if I comment out the `string = data.read().replace('\n', '')` from the first piece of code, I can run the second piece without problem and get the expected output.

Basically, how do I set this up so that I can run the second piece of code on `data`, as well as textstat on `string`?

Comment: When the second portion runs?when `string = data.read().replace('\n', '')` is `uncommented` or `commented`?

Comment: I do apologize, fixed the typo now. I meant that when I comment out the ``string = ... `` the second piece of code will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `data.read()` places the file pointer at the end of the file, so you dont have anything more to read at this point. You either have to close and reopen the file or more simply reset the pointer at the begining using `data.seek(0)`

Comment: Thank you for this, adding ``data.seek(0)`` at the top of the second piece of code made it run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First see the line:

```
string = data.read().replace('\n', '')
```

You are reading from data once. Now, cursor is in the end of data.

Then see the line,

```
for line in data:
```

You are trying to read it again, but you just can't do it, because there is nothing else in data, you are at the end  of it.so `len(word_list)` are returning 0.

You are dividing by it and getting the error.

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.

But when you comment it, now you are reading only once, which is valid, so second portion of your codes now work.

Clear now?

So, what to do now?

Use `data.seek()` after `data.read()`

Demo:

```
>>> a = open('file.txt')
>>> a.read()
#output
>>>a.read()
#nothing
>>> a.seek(0)
>>> a.read()
#output again
```

Comment: Very much so, I am still a bit too used to these operations in PHP where I would have stored it as a string earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple fix. Replace the line `for line in data:` by :

```
data.seek(0)
for line in data.readlines():
  ...
```

It basically points back to the beginning of the file and read it again line by line.

While this should work, you may want to simplify the code and read the file only once. Something like:

```
with open(file, "r") as fin:
  lines = fin.readlines()
  string = ''.join(lines).replace('\n', '')
```